# Strapi post request with relation

Tags: axios, next.js, strapi

I'm trying to do a POST to the Strapi API and can't seem to figure out how to attach a 'has and belongs to one' (one to one) relationship from the profile to the user.

I know the relationship works well because in the admin panel I can create the relationship without any problem

I've already tried the following body's:

```json
{
  "fullName":"Test Name",
  "country": "Nigeria",
  "phone": "09070933598",
  "verified": true,
  "users_permissions_user": {
    "id": 22
  }
}
```

I got this response

```json
{
  "id": 3,
  "users_permissions_user": {},
  "fullName": "Test Name",
  "country": "Nigeria",
  "verified": true,
  "plan": null,
  "earnings": 0,
  "availableBalance": 0,
  "planRegDate": null,
  "planActive": false,
  "planPaymentVerified": false,
  "phone": "09070933598",
  "published_at": "2021-10-19T08:43:04.412Z",
  "created_at": "2021-10-19T08:43:04.428Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-10-19T08:43:04.470Z",
  "identification": null
}
```

I expect to at least have some info about the user with the id passed in the body. It isn't just linking them

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the id of one of the users already in your strapi database to "users_permissions_users".
You can get this from the user object.

```
{
  "fullName":"Test Name",
  "country": "Nigeria",
  "phone": "09070933598",
  "verified": true,
  "users_permissions_user": user.id
}
```